Do Carmos's Riemannian Geometry Proposition 2.6 Chapter 7
The proposition claims that the metric topology on a Riemannian manifold is the same as the original topology. Usually this theorem is proven before showing that exponential map is a local diffeomorphism.
I do not know if Do Carmo uses implicitly this fact but he argues that for small enough metric balls every two points are connected by a minimizing geodesic which implies that metric balls coincide with geodesic balls for small radii.
So how can one see that if the distance between two points is small enough there is a geodesic between these two points?

Which of the two do Carmo's books are you reading and what exactly in the proof don't you understand (and please do not refer to what is "usually" done).

To show that $\exp_p$ is a local diffeomorphism you need only to compute its differential at $p$, which is non-degenerate. The metric and the metric topology need not be used here.
